# How to declare operator<< for internal class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, forward-declaration, nested-class

```
//cannot declare operator<<(...) here:
//forward declarations:
class External;

template<class T, class Y>
class External::Internal;

template<class T, class Y>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const External::Internal<T,Y>&);

class External
{
    template<class T, class Y>
    class Internal
    {};

    Internal data_;

    void print() {
        /*out is a std::ostream*/
        out << data_;
    }
};

template<class T, class Y>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const External::Internal<T,Y>&)
{ }
```

I do want to implement `operator<<` for `Internal` but there is a problem when I try to use this operator call from `External`: It doesn't see this operator when this operator is declared under the definition of this class, and there seems to be no way of declaring this operator above this class definition.

Comment: Why isn't `Internal` qualified properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking how to define `Internal<>::operator<<` as a friend, then:

```cpp
class External
{
  template<class T, class Y>
  class Internal
  {
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Internal&)
    {
      // impl
      return out;
    }
  };

  Internal<Foo, Bar> data_;

public:
  void print() const
  {
    /*out is a std::ostream*/
    out << data_;
  }
};
```

Comment: @ildjarn thanks that works now. But in order to compile you should remove template from operator

Comment: @smallB : "*But in order to compile you should remove template from operator*" Huh? The operator is a template, so obviously it must be defined as a template. This compiles as-is.

Comment: @ildjarn didn't want to compile in VS2010 sp1.

Comment: @ildjarn so why did you say in your previous comment that it DOES compile?

Comment: @smallB : Because it did on the compiler I tested with, which wasn't VC++.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T, class Y>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const External::Internal<T, Y>&)
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^
{

}
```

And make sure to declare this function a `friend`, because `Internal` is private in `External`

***Update:***
here's how you declare a friend. In your class definition write:

```
template<class T, class Y>
friend  std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const External::Internal<T,Y>&)
```

Since a friend-declaration is a declaration, this will solve your forward-declaration issue.

Update: To solve the circular dependency:

First forward-declare `internal`

```
template<class T, class Y>
class Internal;
```

then declare the friend.

Then the rest of your class, it should work.

Comment: @Armen I do have it as you've suggested, but the problem is rather with forward declaration of this operator.

Comment: @small B: What do you mean? How to declare it friend?

Comment: @smallB : What forward declaration? Your code doesn't show one.

Comment: @ildjarn so try make a stub of code I've provided and try to compile it and then you'll see where is the real problem.

Comment: @smallB : Describing your problem is _your_ job; figuring it out independently is not mine.

Comment: @ildjarn ok so if you think that you've figured it out try to compile it and check if it compiles.

Answer (score 1):

[Armen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520605/how-to-declare-operator-for-internal-class/6520631#6520631)'s answer would work for the `<<` operator itself.

However, your member declaration

```
Internal data_;
```

is also incorrect, in the same way. I.e., lacking template arguments for `Internal`. So in addition to fixing your operator implementation, fix also your member declaration.

Finally, remember that in C++ you can't use something unless it has already been declared. Your usage of `<<` in the inline implementation of `print` violates that. So you'd better rearrange things (or just declare them) so that anything that's used, is already declared.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1, that's always my problem when I play chess - I focus on a part of the board, not the whole board :)

Comment: no Armen's answer wouldn't work. There is circular dependency between operator<< and External::Internal. The problem is that you cannot use this operator<< in External before it is declared, and you cannot declare it because you would have to use incomplete type.

Comment: @smallB: possibly you're running into compiler bugs in some old version of MSVC (or for that matter the latest one, haven't checked)? It seems a suitable forward declaration is given in at least two answers here.

Answer (score 1):

The point is in using forward declarations:

```
// you promise there will be implementation of this stuff later on:
template<typename T, typename Y>
class External::Internal<T, Y>;

template<typename T, typename Y>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const External::Internal<T, Y>&);

// now declare your class and operator<< function as normal
class External
{
    template<class T, class Y>
    class Internal
    {
    };

    Internal<Foo, Bar> data_;

    void print()
    {
        // here you can use operator<< with Internal
        out << data_;
    }
};

template<class T, class Y>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,const External::Internal<T, Y>&)
{
}
```

Comment: and did you try to compile it? Try it.

Comment: Right. `Internal` is private, I didn't realize that. In that case declaring a `friend` function is probably the way to go, as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class T, class Y>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const External::Internal<T, Y>&)
{
}
```

The `External::` behaves as a namespace and is required because `operator<<` definition is outside of class External.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a problem when I try to use this operator call from External

Don't write procedural code inside your class definition. Only declarations.

Write, in order:

- Class definition [in header]
- `operator<<` [in header]
- Code that uses these things [in source file]